# Unknown Crashing

Tags: java, android

I am currently trying to develop a simple feature for switching from one page to another but every time I launch the app it crashes.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Screen One......"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/scan"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Click me to another screen" />

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.mdpmk1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button button;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addListenerOnButton();
}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    final Context context = this;

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scan);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ScanScreen.class);
            startActivity(intent);   

        }

     });

   }

}
```

ScanScreen.java

```
package com.example.mdpmk1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;

public class ScanScreen extends Activity {

Button button;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.scan_screen);
  }

}
```

scan_screen.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="You have done it!!"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Im quite new to this sort of stuff but i am doing an app for my major at school and would like to have it actually working. Any help would be lovely. Thanks

Comment: What are the errors that you are receiving when trying to compile and run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to write following statement in your MainActivity's onCreate() method,

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Write here,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

Button button;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     // You forgot this line
        addListenerOnButton();
    }
```

Also change following line of code,

```
public void onClick(View arg0) 
{
     Intent intent = new Intent( MainActivity.this, ScanScreen.class );  // Change here
     startActivity(intent);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your MainActivity onCreate you need to add

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try editing intent statement in class MainActivity to:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ScanScreen.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

You must also add:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

in your ActivityMain class onCreate function to set a view.

Answer (score 0):

`setContentView(R.your_layout)` doesnt exists in your MainActivity's onCreate(). Try providing your activity a layout.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, add SetContentView(R.layout.activity_main) in your MainActivity.OnCreate method befor call to addListenerOnButton.
then be sure that you add your activities entries in your manifest.xml and make MainActivity as your Main Application Activity, like below:

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".ScanScreen"/>
```